# Document body is not loading

Tags: node.js, express

I made a nodejs server, that sends the file index.html, when I enter it, the body of the file isn't showing, only what I wrote in the head is showing, this is what I use to send the file:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

EDIT: when I look at the 'Network' tab in the chrome dev tab, and I look at the response the body is there, but on the docuemnt itself it's empty

Screenshots: [image: Empty body]

[image: Response]

Comment: Show us more code and screenshots, this way now it's complicated to help you...

Comment: Could be broken HTML in the file, if the browser isn't rendering it.

Comment: I just typed some test code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like the only load that's happening is the HTML file itself, but the scripts are not loading.  The browser by design will pause rendering until those script files are loaded and parsed.  Take the script tags out, you should see it render your test message.

The reason the script files aren't loading may be the URLs; the one for socket.io looks wrong to me (unless you have a folder in your app called /socket.io anyway)